Django proyect tring to integrate asgi
I have a django proyect that works with views and django-rest-framework and now i want to add channels to it.
I have a django proyect that works with views and django-rest-framework and now i want to add channels to it so my Django project could support both HTTP and WebSocket connections. My question is there is a way of doing this? I have to rewrite my proyect to use asgi?. I found that channels_redis could do the thrick but I'm not sure

It's not clear what your question is. Have you tried running your project using an ASGI application server? Did anythning go wrong? ASGI supports sync views as well as async ones.
